# MongoDB with php can't create session

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I can create a session locally by using mongo shell and remotely by using vscode 
 mongo plugin(Azure Cosmos DB).

But with [PHP Mongo driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.requirements.php), it doesn't work:

```
MongoDB \ Driver \ Exception \ RuntimeException (11002)
Could not generate UUID for logical session id, we need a cryptography library like libcrypto, Common Crypto, or CNG
```

This error message is reported by php. No errors occurs on monogo.log

- php version: 7.2.3, mongo version: 4.0.2.
- both php-fpm and mongod are listening on the same ubuntu server.
- both php-fpm and mongod has openssl enabled.
- libcrypto and pkg-config is installed on this server(I don't know 
  php will read it or not).

Comment: Solved. after reinstall php mongo extension and restart.